# echo does not print line breaks at the end of a variable

Tags: bash, echo

I am trying to print the content of a variable in a bash script. I need all the line breaks just as in the string, especially in the end of it.

Given an example file:

```
$ touch test.txt
$ echo "A" >> test.txt 
$ echo "B" >> test.txt 
$ echo "C" >> test.txt 
$ echo "" >> test.txt 
$ echo "" >> test.txt
```

`cat test.txt` will print:

```
$ cat test.txt 
A
B
C


$
```

(with two additional line breaks. Added `$` for formatting).

However, If I run `echo`, it returns

```
$ var=$(cat test.txt)
$ echo $var
A B C
$ echo "$var"
A
B
C
```

Adding quotation marks only prints line breaks in the middle of the string, not at the end.

How can I print the trailing line breaks?

Comment: Command substitution will remove trailing newlines, but you can use `read` like this instead: `IFS= read -rd '' var < test.txt`.